# How to convert bloburl/objecturl for Google Apps Script createFile() API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

The code below contains the **createFile()** API, it expects a single object (named "file" here). In this way the file can be saved in some google drive folder

```
function uploadFiles(data)
{
 var file = data;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1UWGb5Mzr9VzPUuQTr9CWD7EMYNEAzyuC');
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
}
```

Now I want to combine this function to another webpage. However, the script in another webpage is below:

```
      for (clipIndex = 0; clipIndex < unrollWordCounts(getAllWantedWords()).length; clipIndex++) {
        try {
          var clip = allClips[clipIndex];
          clip.style.display = 'None';
          var audioBlobUrl = clip.querySelector('audio').src;
          var word = clip.querySelector('p').innerText;
          var filename = word + '_' + Date.now() + '.ogg';
          saveAs(audioBlobUrl, filename);
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(audioBlobUrl);
        }
```

The data I want to upload to google drive is **audioBlobUrl**. However, the **createFile()** of app script expect a file. It seems like **audioBlobUrl** is not a file.
How should I modify the code, so that it can pass the expected data to google **createFile()** to achieve my aim?

Comment: About `another webpage` in your question, in this case, which is the web page on Google or other site? If the web page is on Google, the simple method using `google.script.run` can be used. But if the web page is not on Google, it is required to deploy your Google Apps Script as Web Apps and send the data with the HTTP request from the Javascript side. How about this?

Comment: the webpage is on google and in the same app script project. 
I have no issue calling the app script functions. 
The problem is I can't get the right data type that is suitable to pass into the app script createFile() function

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the webpage is on google and in the same app script project. I have no issue calling the app script functions.`, can you provide your script? Because, unfortunately, from your showing script, I cannot know about your script for communicating to Google Apps Script side. So I cannot imagine `The problem is I can't get the right data type that is suitable to pass into the app script createFile() function`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Let me clarify. The way I use to communicate with app script is using `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(audioBlobUrl)`. 

It replaces the position of `saveAs()` in the current post.

And it doesn't work as I expected since audioBlobUrl is not a correct datatype. The createFile function expects a datatype of file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your replying, I confirmed that your `audioBlobUrl` is like `blob:https://n-gtuqz5opiogjdwjt5bm3j7sgiq5rl4g7osg6piq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/a9f62d15-c7c1-41c0-ac5d-0a05dcb01fa6`. In this case, unfortunately, this URL cannot be directly used. So in order to use this at Google Apps Script, it is required to convert to the data. In this answer, I would like to propose the sample script for converting the URL to the data (in this case, the URL is converted to the byte array.). By this, the data can be decoded at Google Apps Script, and the data can be saved as a file.

### Modified script:

#### Javascript side:

As a simple sample script, When your `audioBlobUrl` and `filename` are used, please use the following script.

```
fetch(audioBlobUrl).then(r => r.blob()).then(blob => {
  var fr = new FileReader;
  fr.onload = f => {
    var obj = {data: [...new Int8Array(f.target.result)], mimeType: blob.type, filename};
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(obj);
  };
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
});
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

At the Google Apps Script side, please modify `uploadFiles` as follows.

```js
function uploadFiles({data, mimeType, filename}) {
  var file = Utilities.newBlob(data, mimeType, filename || "sampleFilename");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1UWGb5Mzr9VzPUuQTr9CWD7EMYNEAzyuC');
  var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
  return createFile.getUrl();
}
```

### Note:

- `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. It seems that `google.script.run` is used in a loop. Although I'm not sure about your whole script, if the asynchronous process will become your new issue, please modify it.
- This modified script supposes that your `audioBlobUrl` is like `blob:https://n-gtuqz5opiogjdwjt5bm3j7sgiq5rl4g7osg6piq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/a9f62d15-c7c1-41c0-ac5d-0a05dcb01fa6` from your replying. Please be careful this.
- I'm not sure about your actual situation from your question. When you are using your script as the Web Apps, when you modified the script, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives an **uncaught error on uploadFiles** on console. Let me give more context about audioBlobUrl to you. I have tried using the following code to test audioBlobUrl
    `async function createAndSaveFile(audioBlobUrl,filename){
      let blob = await fetch(audioBlobUrl).then(r => r.blob());
      console.log(blob);
      saveAs(blob);
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(blob);
    }`

Comment: the saveAs() saved the **blob** converted from audioBlobUrl to my local pc successfully. So it seems like the **blob** and **audioBlobUrl** has no problem. However, when I pass the **blob** to uploadFiles(), it gives **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property:** I wonder how am I using the folder.createFile() in a wrong way.

Comment: @owo ouo Thank you for replying. My proposed answer supposes that your URL of `audioBlobUrl` is the valid direct link of the file as I have already mentioned in my answer. About `It gives an uncaught error on uploadFiles on console.`, I'm worried that your URL might not be the direct link. Can I ask you about this? And, about your script in the comment, unfortunately, Blob of Javascript cannot be directly used with Google Apps Script. Please be careful this. Can I ask you about your URL of `audioBlobUrl`? If you can do, please provide the sample URL of `audioBlobUrl`?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yeah I did read through what you said in answer.
This is one example of the information given by console.log(audioBlobUrl):
`blob:https://n-gtuqz5opiogjdwjt5bm3j7sgiq5rl4g7osg6piq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/a9f62d15-c7c1-41c0-ac5d-0a05dcb01fa6`
Is there anyway I can upload the blob to my google drive?

Comment: @owo ouo Thank you for replying. From your provided URL, in this case, can you provide the script of `the saveAs() saved the blob converted from audioBlobUrl to my local pc successfully.`? Because in this case, that URL cannot be directly used in Google Apps Script.

Comment: The saveAs is from FileSaver.js library. You may refer to this link https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/dist/FileSaver.js

Comment: @owo ouo Thank you for replying. In your HTML, `src` of the tag `audio` is the URL like `blob:https://n-gtuqz5opiogjdwjt5bm3j7sgiq5rl4g7osg6piq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/a9f62d15-c7c1-41c0-ac5d-0a05dcb01fa6`. Is my understanding correct? For example, I thought that when `src` is put from a file or a data from other site, the original data might be able to be directly used. How about this?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand what you say since my web development level is not quite high. let me share the project to you so that you don't need to guess.
https://script.google.com/d/1JqfTdr31-748oautROhKDOeSlB3xcza8Dz_7UJnGQRB5G6PWCIMCJCXW/edit?usp=sharing
Most of the content of the html code is not written by me, I am just trying to modify it. Aiming to Making user can upload their recording to my google drive instead of only download.

Comment: @owo ouo Thank you for replying. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In this updated script, your URL of `audioBlobUrl` like `blob:https://n-gtuqz5opiogjdwjt5bm3j7sgiq5rl4g7osg6piq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/a9f62d15-c7c1-41c0-ac5d-0a05dcb01fa6` can be converted to the byte array. And, this byte array can be saved as a file using Google Apps Script.

Comment: @owo ouo Now I noticed that I overlooked `bloburl/objecturl` in your title. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you, it did work! I have researched on this problem for half of the day. I just cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @owo ouo Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.